# Distance between the minimum of two strongly convex functions and the minimum of their sum

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be two strongly convex functions from a convex set $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, with minimum $x$ and $y$ respectively.
Let us denote by $z$ the minimum of $f+g$, and by $\delta$ the distance $\lVert x-y\rVert$.

I would like to know if it is possible to prove that $\lVert x-z\rVert \leq \delta$ and $\lVert y-z\rVert < \delta$.

Rk:

- This statement is true in one dimension (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503543/minimum-of-sum-of-convex-functions-single-dimension))
- This statement is also true when $f$ and $g$ are two quadratic functions.

Comment: I think it would suffice to show that $z$ must reside in the convex hull of the minimizers of $f$ and $g$, right?

Comment: This is not always the case for dimension higher than 1. Take for example $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $g(x,y)=20(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2$. The minimum of $f$ is $z_f=(0, 0)$, and the minimum of $g$ is $z_g=(1, 1)$, but the minimum of $f+g$ is $(\frac{10}{11}, \frac{1}{2})$, which is not in the convex hull of $\{x ,y\}$.

Comment: However, because it is true in one dimension, applying it on all coordinates, we get that $z_{f+g}$ will be in the hypercube defined by $z_f$ and $z_g$. That is to say, that for any $1\leq i \leq n$, $[\min(z_{f,i}, z_{g,i}) \leq z_{f+g, i} \leq \max(z_{f,i}, z_{f,j})]$, which solve the question.

Comment: Interesting point! So, I suppose if we use the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ metric then we are fine. What about others?

Comment: We are still fine with all of the $\lVert\cdot\rVert_p$ metrics, because $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (z_{f,i}−z_{f+g,i})^p\right)^{(1/p)}\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (z_{f,i}−z_{g,i})^p\right)^{(1/p)}=\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

This result is true at least for any $p$-norm with $p\geq 1$.
Indeed, we know that the result is true in one dimension (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503543/minimum-of-sum-of-convex-functions-single-dimension)).
Thus, the result is still true if we apply it to each of the coordinates of the functions $f$ and $g$.

In particular, we get:
$$ \forall 1 \leq i \leq n,\ \min(x_i, y_i) \leq z_i \leq \max(x_i, y_i) $$

This shows us that
$$ \lVert x-z \rVert_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-z_i)^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^p\right)^{1/p} = \lVert x_i - y_i \rVert_p =\delta $$
By symmetry, the same result holds for $y$: $\lVert y-z \rVert_p \leq \delta$.

Comment: From the counterexample in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983368/the-minimum-of-the-sum-of-two-convex-functions, I think your statement about the range of $z_i$ is not true in general.

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much, I will delete my answer. Sadly it is not a counter example to my question...

Comment: You don't have to delete (and I didn't downvoted it either). I think it's still valuable to know that the OP's question is derivable from that particular assumption.